# Login using Class based view didn't work as expected while trying to login a user using email

Tags: django-views, django-class-based-views

my views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import View
from .forms import LoginForm, RegistrationForm


class Login(View):
    form_class = LoginForm
    initial = {'key': 'value'}
    template_name = 'web/login.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.form_class(initial=self.initial)
            if form.is_valid():
                email=form.cleaned_data['email']
                password=form.cleaned_data['password']
                auser = User.objects.get(email=email)
                username = auser.username
                buser = authenticate(username, password)
                if buser:
                    if buser.is_active:
                        login(request, buser)
                        return HttpResponse('Good to Go...')
                    else:
                        return HttpResponse('your account is disabled...')
                else:
                    print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(email, password)
                    HttpResponse('invalid login details...')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Form is not valid!')
        else:
            form = self.form_class()
```

Here above I'm trying to login a user using email as unique field in  class based views. But It raises 'Form is not valid!' as I specified in my views. I don't know what's going wrong with it exactly. Please Help me how to fix it?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the post method of this class:

```
def post(self, request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = self.form_class(data=self.request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        .....
```